# Do we need to restart Glassfish server/application after changing configuration on server/application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Currently on glassfish 3.1 and working on the GUI mode

I wonder whether need to restart glassfish server when add new Realm/user/group

AND

whether need to restart application after make change to web.xml/SUN-WEB.xml

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it without a restart? What was the result?

Comment: @Tichodroma Seems change doesn't apply, but not sure whether it is from the problem of the configuration itself. I heard about hotdeploy application on glassfish with NetBeans, but not sure that includes the server settings. Need to mention that on the GUI interface/Server page sometimes it says "Require to restart" so make me hold a line of hope that it even support hot deploy on server settings....